# How to set the height of the title in the appbar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, appbar

In my Flutter app, I have an `AppBar` and the `title` of it is a clickable `InkWell`.

My issue is that this clickable area is not the full height of the app bar - it is just a thin slither the height of the title text - and I want, for more pleasing UI, for the clickable area to be the full height of the app bar.
(Note that it is not the full width, and I achieve that by wrapping the InkWell in `Padding`)

**How can I make the title text in the app bar have more height?**

(Or otherwise achieve making my ink well be the full height of the AppBar)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

**Instead of using the `title` property in the `AppBar`, use the `flexibleSpace` property.**

And set the `height` of the `Container` you wrap your `InkWell` in, to a value of `preferredSize.height` (meaning, get the height of the AppBar itself).

```dart
      AppBar(
          flexibleSpace: Container( 
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 0, 100, 0),
            height: preferredSize.height,
            child: InkWell(
```